# Datetime format PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following problem. I have a string, which contains time and date as follows:
dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss
This I have in PHP. And then I have a MySQL database, which has a column of a datetime format, where I need to insert this value. Obviously the problem is, that the format is different, so instead of the actual date, it results in a field "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

Could you please help me with converting this string and then inserting it properly into MySQL?
For the MySQL I use the standard INSERT INTO command.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to parse the string and build new date from the values you get? Doesn't look all that hard.

Answer (score 7):

From the [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) documentation:

> MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

I'd use PHP's DateTime class and [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method, and convert the data into a MySQL-compatible date string, like so:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $yourDateString);
$dateToBeInserted = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to convert date,

```
function sqldate($date)
{
   $sql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date));
   return $sql_date;
}
```

And your query look like,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tableName (dateColumn) VALUES('".sqldate($date)."') ";
```

Comment: strtotime() will treat xx/yy/zz as a US format date(mm/dd/yy) rather than as UK format (dd/mm/yy)... you'll need to replace `/` with `-` for a UK date to be recognised correctly (dd-mm-yy)

Comment: for some reason, if I echo the string Im getting:

Comment: @user2370078 Let me know what you are passing to the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it using [*STR_TO_DATE()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fstr-to-date) along with your `INSERT` statement, eg.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (dateColumn)
VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss','%d/%m/%y %H:%i:%s'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/416a9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$parsedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($yourDate));
// Insert $parsedDate into your table column Date
```

Comment: strtotime() will treat xx/yy/zz as a US format date(mm/dd/yy) rather than as UK format (dd/mm/yy)... you'll need to replace `/` with `-` for a UK date to be recognised correctly (dd-mm-yy)